# Login route redirecting to index route but not specified anywhere but single middleware

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I have a login route that uses passport local with a custom passport strategy called `login`. When I send a post request to `/login` it receives it and then redirects to the `/` index route. This can only be caused by my `isUnauthenticated` middleware.

Something is going wrong in my passport strategy but I am unsure of where it is failing. I know that it is not logging in a user but unsure why. No stack trace or anything and my basic logging at this point just shows the routes being hit and their status codes.

If I remove the auth middleware I just get the login route handing and returning no error other than timing out.

**isUnauthenticated middleware**

```
exports.isUnauthenticated = function(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.isAuthenticated()){
    return next();
  }

  res.redirect('/');
};
```

**login route**

```
app.post('/login', isUnauthenticated, sessions.postLogin);
```

**sessions.postLogin**

```
exports.postLogin = (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('login', {
        successRedirect : '/profile',
        failureRedirect : '/login', 
        failureFlash : true 
    })
};
```

**passport strategy**

```
passport.use('login', new LocalStrategy({
      usernameField: 'email',
      passReqToCallback : true
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) {

      User.findOne({ 'email' :  email },
        function(err, user) {
          if (err) return done(err);
          if (!user){
            return done(null, false, req.flash('error', 'User not found'));
          }
          user.comparePassword(password, function(err, isMatch) {
            if(err){
              console.log(err);
            }
            if (isMatch) {
              // Make sure the user has been verified
              if (!user.isVerified) return done (null, false, req.flash('error', 'Your account has not been verified.' ));
              var time = 14 * 24 * 3600000;
              req.session.cookie.maxAge = time; //2 weeks
              req.session.cookie.expires = new Date(Date.now() + time);
              req.session.touch();
              return done(null, user, req.flash('success', 'Successfully logged in.'));
            } else {
              return done(null, false, req.flash('error', 'Invalid Password'));
            }

          });
        }
      );
    })
  );
```

Comment: What if you return done(err); instead of conosle.log(err)?  No idea what's going on without seeing some logging.

Comment: @user2263572 There is no logging set up at this point. It is a new application and node is not spitting out any errors. I changed the console.log to done and it didn't change anything. With the auth middleware removed it times out and gives no error or log

Comment: That's fair.  But some well placed console.logs and a screenshot of the terminal output would probably help others help you.  Otherwise it's difficult to try to guess what is being executed. No need for any advanced logging.

Comment: I'm still working on putting in console.log statements but finding places that are running and returning correctly is proving hard. I did put in a `console.log(req.isAuthenticated())` and that returns false when I put it directly in the route but if I put it in the middleware it just hangs

Comment: @user2263572 See my answer I posted for how I fixed it. Maybe you can explain why I needed that.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding `(req, res, next);` to the end of the `session.postLogin` controller. The new session.postLogin looks like this:

```
exports.postLogin = (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('login', {
        successRedirect : '/profile',
        failureRedirect : '/login', 
        failureFlash : true 
    })(req, res, next);  <-- this was what I needed to add. Not sure why though. 
};
```